# Selenium POM + Extent Report - getting error message

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extent

Hi I am using POM/Selenium/Java, and I am getting below error message. Can we use it extent report in POM?, can we call it (Extent Methods) from different class?.

Or do you have other reports suggestions?, please let me know.

**Edited:** My intention is I have created generic functions for `sendkeys`, click, etc so I want to use in this generic level only (I do not want to use at object level).

1. Using extent report version: extentreports-java-v2.41.1
2. Using property file

**Error message for dropdown:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException at  testCase.LoginPage.TestBase.seleteDropDownVisibleText(TestBase.java:217)

**Code to select dropdown value + Extent logger:**

```
public void seleteDropDownVisibleText(WebElement element, String string){
    try 
    {
        Select select = new Select(element);
        select.selectByVisibleText(string);
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Selecting "+string+" value in dropdown");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        logger.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Not selected "+string+" value in dropdown");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And I am calling select dropdown value (VisibleText) function like this:**

```
public void billingType() 
{
    seleteDropDownVisibleText(lstBillingType,  Repository.getProperty("visible"));
}
```

**Error message for sendkeys:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at testCase.LoginPage.TestBase.textBox(TestBase.java:241)
```

**Code for sendkeys + Extent logger:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at testCase.LoginPage.TestBase.textBox(TestBase.java:241)
```

**And I am calling textBox (SendKeys) function like this:**

```
textBox(username, Repository.getProperty("login.txtUserName"));
textBox(password, Repository.getProperty("login.txtPassword"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below link for your question, may this will solve your issue.

[Link](https://github.com/AbedEl-Rahman/FacebookTestExtentReport/blob/master/src/testCases/SignUpConfirm.java)

```
String ScreenShotPath = Utility.CaptureScreenShots(driver,result.getName());
 String image = logger.addScreenCapture(ScreenShotPath);
 logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Title",image);
```